# Expressing $ (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $ in terms of powers of $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing my preview while some problems turned out to make me feel sucky.

It's said that every element $ x $ of $ (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $ could be expressed **uniquely** as
$$ x \equiv\pm 5^{\alpha} \bmod 2^k $$
where $ 1\le\alpha\le 2^{k-2} $, and the exponent $$ e=2^{k-2} $$
which I understood as the $ l.c.m $ of the orders of all $ x \in (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $ equals to $ 2^{k-2} $

All these above were written in my teacher's PPT for the number theory class. Since I'm doing a preview, I don't quite get that. Why is it and how to understand it?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $(1+2^2)^{2^m} \equiv 1+2^{m+2}\bmod 2^{m+3}$ thus the order of $5\bmod 2^k$ is $2^{k-2}$ and $\{\pm 5^a,a\in 1,\ldots,2^{k-2}\}$ is a set with $2^{k-1}$ distinct elements.

Comment: @reuns, Sorry but why is the minus sign appropriate to be written here?

Comment: The powers of $5$ give $2^{k-2}$ elements, adding $\pm$ gives the whole $2^{k-1}$ elements of the group

Comment: Why is $ +5^m \equiv -5^n \bmod 2^k $ not true?

Comment: Reduce $\bmod 4$

Comment: Thanks but actually you could edit it by yourself.@BillDubuque

Answer (score 2):

The following is an excerpt from a book whose draft I wrote last year. It answers your question in essentially the same way as in the comments by reuns, but in explicit detail.

**Problem.** Take the following steps for all integers $n\ge 3$:

1. Prove by induction on $n$ that $\nu_2 \left(5^{2^{n-2}}-1\right) =
       n.$
2. Show that the $\text{ord}_{2^n}(5) = 2^{n-2}.$
3. Deduce that
   $S=\left\{\pm 5^k : k\in \left[2^{n-2}\right] \right\}$ is a reduced
   residue system modulo $2^n.$

*Solution.* Each step leads to the next one.

1. We will show by induction on $n\ge 3$ that, for each integer $n\ge 3,$ there exists an odd integer $x_n$ such that $5^{2^{n-2}} = 1 + x_n \cdot 2^n.$ Since $x_n$ will be shown to be odd, no power of $2$ higher than $2^n$ can divide $5^{2^{n-2}}-1,$ while it is true that $2^n$ does divide $5^{2^{n-2}}-1.$ Thus, we will have proven that $\nu_2 \left(5^{2^{n-2}}\right) = n.$

   The base case $n=3$ holds because $$5^{2^{3-2}} - 1 = 24 = 3\cdot 2^3.$$ Now suppose $5^{2^{n-2}} = 1 + x_n \cdot 2^n$ for some integer $n\ge 3$ and odd integer $x_n.$ Squaring the equation yields
   $$5^{2^{n-1}} = 1 + x_n \cdot 2^{n+1} + x_n^2 \cdot 2^{2n} = 1 + x_n(1+x_n 2^{n-1})\cdot 2^{n+1}\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+1}}.$$ Since $x_n$ is odd and $n\ge 3,$ so is $$x_{n+1}=x_n(1+x_n 2^{n-1}).$$
2. We know from the first part that $$5^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1\pmod{2^n}.$$ So the order of $5$ modulo $2^n$ must divide $2^{n-2}.$ Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an integer $i$ such that $3\le i\le n$ and $5^{2^{n-i}}\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}.$ Squaring this sufficiently many times (taking it to an exponent of $2^{i-3},$ to be precise) we get $5^{2^{n-3}} \equiv 1\pmod{2^n}.$ So there exists an integer $y_n$ such that $$5^{2^{n-3}} = 1 + y_n 2^n.$$ Squaring this yields $$5^{2^{n-2}} = 1 + y_n 2^{n+1} + y_n^2 2^{2n} = 1+(2y_n + y_n^2 2^n)2^n,$$ which implies that the $x_n$ from the last part is the even number $2y_n + y_n^2 2^n$. This is a contradiction.
3. Note that the order of $5$ modulo $2^n$ is $2^{n-2}=\frac{\varphi(2^n)}{2}$ and that the elements of $S$ are all in fact units. We could show that $S$ consists of precisely all of the units (that is, invertible elements, which are the odd integers in this case) by showing that none of the $5^i$ coincide with the $-5^j$ modulo $2^n.$ If $5^i\equiv -5^j\pmod {2^n}$ then cancelling the smaller of the two powers from both sides (or either, if they are equal) would yield a power of $5$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $2^n.$ It suffices to show that $$5^k \not\equiv -1\pmod{2^n}$$ for all $k.$ If the congruence held, then we could reduce it to $$5^k \equiv -1 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$$ using $4\mid 2^n.$ This is contradictory because $$5^k \equiv 1^k \equiv 1\pmod{4}.$$ Therefore, there are no overlaps between the $5^i$ and $-5^j.$ This produces $$2\cdot 2^{n-2}=2^{n-1}=\varphi(2^n)$$ distinct units modulo $2^n,$ which is the maximal number and so this is the set of all units modulo $2^n.$

Comment: I have a question about #2 the $\text{ord}_{2^n}(5)=2^{n-2}$ holds for $n=2,3,4$ so I'm wondering if one could then argue that for $5^{{2}^{n-2-i}}\equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$ then $5^{2^{n-2-i}} = 1+2^{n-i}\cdot x_{n-i} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$ because $x_{n-i} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for $1\leq i\leq n-3$ for  $n\geq 5$ and if $i=n-2$ then $5^{2^0}\equiv 5^1 \equiv 5 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$??

Comment: @nolemonnomelon Sorry, but unfortuantely I don't understand your notation $x_{n-i}$ or your line of logic or what you are asking. Are you saying that there is a flaw in my proof or something else? Certainly there are elements with lower orders, as you can compute to check on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: No flaw, not at all, I was wondering if you could prove instead that there are no lower powers of $2$ such that $5^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$ because you proved that for $5^{2^{n-2}}=1+2^n \cdot x_n$ where $x_n$ is odd, and so any lower power $5^{2^{n-2-i}}$ it is equal to $1+2^{n-i}\cdot x_{n-i}$ (let's assume $n\geq 5$) for $0\leq i \leq n-3$ where $x_{n-i}$ is odd, thus $1+2^{n-i}x_{n-i} \not\equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$ because that would imply $2^n | 2^{n-i}x_{n-i}$ which is impossible because $x_{n-i}$ is odd

Comment: Basically I'm going down through each power $2$ in $5^{2^{n-2}}=1+2^n\cdot x_n$ until I get to $5^{2^0} = 5=1+2^2\cdot 1$, any power of $2$ less than $n-2$ cannot be $\equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$ by the above argument I typed up, and I also assumed $n\geq 5$ thus in the case $i=n-2$, $5 \not\equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$ because $5 < 32$. So after going all the way down to $5^{2^0}$, none satisfy the property of being $\equiv 1$ for a lower power of $2$ than $n-2$, since $\text{ord}_{2^n}(5)|\phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$, $\text{ord}_{2^n}(5)=2^{n-2}$ for $n\geq 5$, the cases $n<5$ are easy to prove